# How to retrieve data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, object, firebase

I'm having a little trouble retrieving data from firebase in a specific format, though it seems it should be simple.

The database endpoint containers this data in this format:

```
{
    "A": {
        "width": 120,
        "height": 130
    },
    "B": {
        "width": 350,
        "height": 240
    },
    "C": {
        "width": 680,
        "height": 160
}
```

All I want to do is concat the letters with their respective width and height, then push all of the groups into an array and set that equal to 'data' so I can call 'data' anywhere in the program to use it, like so:

```
    var data = [{
    "id" : "A",
    "width": 120,
    "height": 130
}, {
    "id" : "B",
    "width": 350,
    "height": 240
}, {
    "id" : "C",
    "width": 680,
    "height": 160
}];

   // somewhere else in the file
  // data[0].end === 150
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/1ubyfs3m/)

```
var junk = {
    "A": {
        "width": 120,
        "height": 130
    },
    "B": {
        "width": 350,
        "height": 240
    },
    "C": {
        "width": 680,
        "height": 160
        }
};
var data = [];
for (var property in junk) {
    if (junk.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        data.push({
            name:property,
            end: junk[property].width,
            start:junk[property].height
        });
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hey sorry about that. The key/properties are not supposed to change, I accidentally copy/pasted the wrong thing. I edited my original question to reflect the output I want.

Comment: so change them.. whats the problem?

Comment: I wrote the response for the other answer and just pasted it here as well. There is no problem, although your answer doesn't incorporate firebase. I figured it out though

Comment: we're not here to write your code for you. i helped you with the logic, you can change the names yourself. welcome to the community. if i helped please hit the check mark by my answer.

Comment: Oh, so you're the reason people complain about people being a-holes on this site. Got it. I never asked you to re-write everything. I was answering your question. I said I figured it out. I'm not really sure how you confused that with "can you please re-write this for me." Now I'm not checking you off. Welcome to the community.

Comment: whatevs bro. see how far that attitude gets you around here.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're retrieving data from Firebase, you'll get it in a so-called [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start). That class has a convenient [`forEach()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html) method on it, to allow iterating over its children:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    data.push({
        name: child.key(),
        end: child.val().width,
        start: child.val().height
    });
})
```

*I took the logic for `start` and `end` from Pamblam's answer, because I don't understand how that is meant to work.*

Comment: Hey sorry about that. The key/properties are not supposed to change, I accidentally copy/pasted the wrong thing. I edited my original question to reflect the output I want.